# Is it good idea to have parallel processes which append txt file using async fs.appendFile(file, text, callback)

Tags: node.js, io, parallel-processing

I'm developing node.js application which will be started using

```
for(i=0; i<os.cpus().length; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
}
```

Every node worker will write to one common file using asynchronously writing with the node.js function

```
fs.appendFile(file, text, callback)
```

In that case there's parallel writing to one file from each node worker.

I'm not sure whether that parralel appending will slow down saving data to the file. Is it possible the saved data to be corrupted because there's parallel writing?

I'm wondering isn't it better/faster every node worker to write to an own file (i.e if there's 8 workers, the data to be saved in 8 individual file)

The application will be deployed on UNIX based system.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are definitely going to hit data corruption and write lock issues there. Consider either using a real database instead of the filesystem or at the very least give each worker it's own file.